# assigns the argument to the attribute Java

Tags: java

I am having some trouble with some homework. I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong :)

This is what I have to do:

*Now add a method to class Customer that takes an object of type BankAccount as
argument and assigns the argument to the attribute myBankAccount. You may want
to use the following method heading:*

```
public void addAccount(BankAccount account);
```

So I have to assign the class BankAccount to an attribute in a method in my other class called Customer.

This sound straightforward for me, but I get an error when I try to run the program.

```
 public void addAccount(BankAccount account)
 {
     account = myBankAccount;
 }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: My error is , that when i am trying to call the method, and create a new account for the Customer i get and " Cant find symbol error".

Comment: I guess it needs to create a new account but i just dont see it in the qustion that i have to do anything else than assign the class to a attribute am i right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just flip your logic around.

Assignment is:

```
{instance} {operator} {parameter}
```

```java
class Customer {
    private BankAccount myBankAccount;

    public void addAccount(BankAccount account) {
        this.myBankAccount = account;
    }
}
```

**Refer to**: [Java 7 Spec: 15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator =](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, sorry i was just going on to fast , the code was not supose to create an new account yet , in the next assignment i will need to add more logic to the add acount method .. but thanks for the quick eye i had turn it the wrong way the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, the target of the assignment is the left-hand side:

```
myBankAccount = account;
```

Comment: Thank you! :) ... But i am still getting the "error"